# Avoid loading whole object graph in RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a domain object mapped with JPA annotations. The `User` have many `Question` objects (could be 1000nds). I had to set the fetch type on the list of questions in the user object to `eager`. I have a path like this in the web service:

`GET /users/3`

This of course returns the user object, and all the questions that he/she has authored. The `Question` have its own relations and so on...

My consern is that it takes a little to long to get a particular user. It would be better to get only some questions and then load more as you need too. However, I don't think I could do that with those annotations. So do I need to remove these annotations and instead manually look up questions for a particular user and then assign a subset to the user?

What is the common way to solve such cases in a web service? Example/pseudocode if provided would be much appriciated. I am using Spring MVC 3.2.

Comment: How about implementing pagination in your REST service?

Comment: "My consern is that it takes a little to long to get a particular user".  You mean from the backend or are you talking about the time it takes to send all the data to the client?

Comment: _I had to set the fetch type on the list of questions in the user object to eager_ Why? If you set it to `lazy`, your `User` object will load faster? Are you referencing the `Question` objects anywhere within a session for `eager` to be required?

Comment: I guess this article says it well: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/avoid-lazy-jpa-collections.html That was one of the things I thought of, dropping the collection mappings on some of the entities and have repository layer methods for them instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this.  Here are a few I know of:

1. Don't return the whole user, just return his "top level data".  Have other urls to get the rest of the data.  EG: `/users/1/questions` to get the questions.
2. Pagination, as svz said in a comment.  One way to do this is to let the user pass in a `limit` and an `offset`.
3. A combination of 1 and 2.
4. Sometimes rest apis have an `expand=true` parameter you can pass in.  If it's false, it'll return "top level data".  If it's true, it'll return a user with all of his questions.  You only get all the data if you explicitly ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is the JPA and entities itself. We also have use cases that need to return a very large set of data, but not related data along with it when using JPA + Hibernate. Transform these JPA entities is such a pain.

So, here is how we decide to resolve the problems:

1. Query the data we need with necessary level
2. Detach the object with necessary data
3. Trim/Delete all data/relation we don't need along with an object and it's properties
4. Convert to JSON and return

In case, if you need to maintain the relationship, consider to use graph builder like this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java?r=1170